# What is LATEST_ON syntax in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm using QuestDB and SQL for the first time, and I stumbled upon the LATEST_ON syntax used in QuestDB. Can someone explain it's usage and where to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the docs:

> For scenarios where multiple time series are stored in the same table, it is relatively difficult to identify the latest items of these time series with standard SQL syntax. QuestDB introduces LATEST ON clause for a SELECT statement to remove boilerplate clutter and splice the table with relative ease.

For more information visit the [official documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/latest-on/)

Answer (score 0):

LATEST ON is to find the latest record for each unique time series in a table. See this page for some examples: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/latest-on/

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the latest available record for each combination of the `PARTITION BY` values, according to the `ON` timestamp

Maybe easier to understand with an example. If you go to https://demo.questdb.io you can execute this query

```
select * from trades latest on timestamp 
partition by symbol, side
```

It will then show you the latest existing row for each combination of Symbol and Side. If you wanted to do this using standard SQL, you would probably have to use a window function, something like this

```
select * from
(select *
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Symbol, Side
 order by timestamp DESC) AS RowNumber 
from trades where timestamp > '2022-10-01') t
where t.RowNumber = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest on retrieves the latest entry by timestamp for a given key or combination of keys, for scenarios where multiple time series are stored in the same table.
Check this link for some examples: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/latest-on/